# PRKP-1001 : Error starting instance,CRS-0215 : could not start resource

Tags: oracle, rac

We have 3-node Oracle 10g R2 RAC database. Following is the status of various RAC components:-

```
ora....b2.inst application    ONLINE    OFFLINE  
ora....db2.srv application    ONLINE    ONLINE    ispdbsrv1  
ora....cdb3.cs application    ONLINE    OFFLINE  
ora....b3.inst application    ONLINE    UNKNOWN   ispdbsrv2 
ora....db3.srv application    ONLINE    OFFLINE
```

While starting rac using crs_start -all, following is the output:

```
crs_start -all  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv1.ASM1.asm` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv1.vip` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv2.ASM2.asm` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv2.vip` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv3.vip` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv3.ASM3.asm` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.inst` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv1.vip` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv2.vip` on member `ispdbsrv2` succeeded.  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv2.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV2.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv3.vip` on member `ispdbsrv3` succeeded.  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv1.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV1.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv3.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV3.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
`ora.smcdb.smcdb3.inst` on member `ispdbsrv2` has experienced an unrecoverable failure.  
Human intervention required to resume its availability.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv1.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV1.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv2.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV2.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv2` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv3.LISTENER_ISPDBSRV3.lsnr` on member `ispdbsrv3` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv1.ASM1.asm` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.inst` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv2.ASM2.asm` on member `ispdbsrv2` succeeded.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.inst` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.inst` on member `ispdbsrv2` failed.  
ispdbsrv1 : CRS-1018: Resource ora.ispdbsrv2.ASM2.asm (application) is already running on ispdbsrv2  
ispdbsrv3 : CRS-1018: Resource ora.ispdbsrv2.ASM2.asm (application) is already running on ispdbsrv2  

Start of `ora.ispdbsrv3.ASM3.asm` on member `ispdbsrv3` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.inst` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
CRS-1002: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv1.ons' is already running on member 'ispdbsrv1'  
CRS-1002: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv2.ons' is already running on member 'ispdbsrv2'  
CRS-1002: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv3.ons' is already running on member 'ispdbsrv3'  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv1.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv2.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Attempting to start `ora.ispdbsrv3.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.cs` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.smcdb2.srv` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.cs` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.smcdb1.srv` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv1.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv2.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv2` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.ispdbsrv3.gsd` on member `ispdbsrv3` succeeded.  
CRS-1002: Resource 'ora.smcdb.db' is already running on member 'ispdbsrv2'  

Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.smcdb1.srv` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.smcdb3.srv` on member `ispdbsrv3`  
`ora.smcdb.smcdb3.smcdb3.srv` on member `ispdbsrv3` has experienced an unrecoverable failure.  
Human intervention required to resume its availability.
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.smcdb2.srv` on member `ispdbsrv2` failed.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.smcdb2.srv` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.cs` on member `ispdbsrv2` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb2.smcdb2.srv` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv3` failed.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv1`  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv1` failed.  
Attempting to start `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv2`  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs` on member `ispdbsrv2` failed.  
CRS-1006: No more members to consider  
Start of `ora.smcdb.smcdb1.cs` on member `ispdbsrv1` succeeded.  
CRS-0223: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv1.ons' has placement error.  
CRS-0223: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv2.ons' has placement error.  
CRS-0223: Resource 'ora.ispdbsrv3.ons' has placement error.  
CRS-0223: Resource 'ora.smcdb.db' has placement error.  
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.smcdb.smcdb2.inst'.  
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.smcdb.smcdb3.cs'.  
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.smcdb.smcdb3.inst'.  
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.smcdb.smcdb3.smcdb3.srv'.
```

Got following message in imon_smcdb.log:

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters 



[ora.smcdb.smcdb2.inst]: ORA-01565: error in identifying file  
 '+DB/SMCDB/PARAMETERFILE/spfileSMCDB.ora'  
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DB/SMCDB/PARAMETERFILE/spfileSMCDB.ora  
ORA-15077: could not locate ASM instance serving a required diskgroup
```

output of crsctl check crs  gave healthy status.

Other information:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>srvctl start instance -d smcdb -i smcdb2   PRKP-1001 : Error starting instance smcdb2 on node ispdbsrv2  
CRS-0215: Could not start resource 'ora.smcdb.smcdb2.inst'.  

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>srvctl config database -d smcdb -a  
ispdbsrv2 smcdb3 d:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db  
ispdbsrv2 smcdb2 d:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db  
ispdbsrv1 smcdb1 d:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db  
DB_NAME: null  
ORACLE_HOME: d:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db  
SPFILE: null  
DOMAIN: null  
DB_ROLE: null  
START_OPTIONS: null  
POLICY: AUTOMATIC  
ENABLE FLAG: DB ENABLED
```

Comment: RAC on Windows? Ewwwwww

Comment: yes. Operating System is Windows Server 2003 Std Edition 32-bit

Comment: Did you check that your spfile is accessible? I don‘t know if there is a asmcmd command in 10.2 RAC but did you check all your DG are mounted?

Comment: asmcmd is available in 10.2 RAC.

Comment: So, did you check if you can access your spfile?

Comment: All disk groups are mounted.

Comment: no spfile file found. show parameter spfile gives  nothing in value. Kindly help how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely related to having a corrupt/removed SPFILE, or someone modified the SPFILE with invalid parameters, which is causing the system to act like it doesn't exist.

To fix the problem, you will have to restore the SPFILE for your SMCDB database. Hopefully, you have a backup of your SPFILE somewhere. If not, you can connect to the idle instance and create a temporary pfile (taken from: [Unable to start oracle database after trying to enable archive log mode on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197865/unable-to-start-oracle-database-after-trying-to-enable-archive-log-mode-on))

> Login using sqlplus:
>
> C:>sqlplus / as sysdba
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Feb 14 09:31:21 2018
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to an idle instance. Create a temporary pfile:
>
> SQL> create pfile = 'c:\temp\init.ora' from spfile;
>
> File created.
>
> SQL>  Then you edit that file (c:\temp\init.ora) and remove/fix the
>   parameter for archive destination. Then you do:
>
> startup pfile=c:\temp\init.ora to get your database started, and then
>   issue:
>
> create spfile from pfile = 'c:\temp\init.ora'; and you should be good
>   to go.